# Memory stream not disposed even after calling GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, .net-core, garbage-collection

We have read the **20MB size font file** as a file stream and copy this stream to new memory stream. After that, we have disposed of all streams and also released the memories using GC.Collect. But still, some amount of memory is in use.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    GC.Collect();
    long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Before - " + memory);

    ReadFonts();

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    long memory1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine("After - " + memory1);

    Console.WriteLine("Difference - " + (memory1 - memory));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ReadFonts()
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\simsun.ttc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();            
    stream.Position = 0;                       
    stream.CopyTo(memStream);
    stream.Dispose();
    memStream.Dispose();

    FileStream stream1 = new FileStream(@"D:\msyh.ttc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();           
    stream1.Position = 0;           
    stream1.CopyTo(memStream1);           
    stream1.Dispose();
    memStream1.Dispose();
}
```

[image: memory leak]

How to release all used memories and how to achieve before memory and after memory as same?

Comment: The garbage collector does not guarantee that all inaccessible memory is collected. [Have you read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalmemory?view=net-5.0#remarks) the remarks section?

Comment: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: Better use using-statements or the new using var C#9 feature than explicit calls to Dispose. (Does not fix the problem you mention, so.) `using var stream = new FileStream(...);`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-5.0

Comment: Declare all streams with `using` statements. Remove all `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` stuff. Change the last call in `long memory1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);`. -- `stream.Position = 0;` is useless here. It becomes useful if you read directly from a MemoryStream after (not if you call `[MemoryStream].ToArray()`).

Comment: How to ensure that the streams are disposed properly ?

Comment: *Declare all streams with `using` statements*: `using (var fs = new FileStream(@"...", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) { fs.CopyTo(ms); }`. It's not clear why you're using a FileStream with MemoryStream here, since you just copy the bytes, so you could just have: `var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("[File Path]"));` and return the stream to something that uses it (setting `position = 0;` in advance). Call `Dispose()` on it after use. It depends on the use case. Anyway, that's what the `using` statement is for.